# Be-friend'ing std::tuple

Tags: c++, friend

I have a custom `class`, and I'd like to minimize the chances that someone on my team accidentally copies it, as that could break certain invariants within our system. To this end, I made the copy constructor private, as there is no reason anyone should need to copy it in any legitimate usage of the class.

However, under-the-hood of the framework that the class is a part of, a copy construction of the object into a `std::tuple` is required. I tried to use `friend`, but the compiler still complains, as the inner class(es?) of `std::tuple` require friend-access as well.

What is the best way to get what I want?

Comment: `friend`-ship is the strongest relationship between class types in C++. Do you really want that with a type you didn't even create? Why can `std::tuple` copy it, but no one else can?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you try to solve? Please [read about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BoBTFish I want to prevent unintentional copy-construction due to programmer error. It's purely a practical concern.

Comment: @dshin Unless there is a good reason the type *must* not be copied, you should leave that decision to the user of the type. Why is it correct for `tuple` to do it, but not someone else writing some sort of container that needs it?

Comment: @dshin but by making the copy constructor private, you prevent *all* copy-construction, both intentional and non-intentional. Furthermore, programmers would still be able to make unintentional copies using `tuple`.

Comment: Use a base-class where std::tuple is friend then derive your exposed private-ctor class from that.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, programmers would be able to make unintentional copies using `tuple`. That is unlikely to happen in my context. My actual desire is to prevent *all* copy-construction.

Comment: @slashmais Thanks for the idea, with some refactoring I think I can make that work.

Comment: I reworded my question slightly to answer some of the questions in the comments.

Comment: What negative effects occur if this class is copy-constructed?

Comment: A noble goal, but given that it's troubling and that some code needs to copy your objects anyway, I'd not bother.

Comment: @GManNickG performance (it's a large object), and potential for bugs

Comment: No bugs should occur if you have a properly-defined copy constructor. As for performance, allow programmers to program; if copying your object is needed, let it happen, otherwise pass by reference. Don't contort your code out of (unfounded?) fear that someone will forget a reference. Your profiler will help.

Comment: One thought: make a special function that encapsulates this ability to copy construct.  Then, you can limit friendship to only that function. So, maybe make_special_tuple for your class does everything, and that one function is a friend of your framework.  I feel like encapsulating in a function is the easiest thing to do here.

Comment: @GManNickG Sure, but declaring copy constructors private is fairly common practice, not really a contortion. I've been at companies where you were required to make copy constructors private unless there was a compelling reason not to. Also, the fear of bug is not due to a buggy constructor definition, but that we have >N instances of an object that logically there should only be N instances of. The instance in my tuple doesn't count because it's under a carefully crafted under-the-hood framework.

Comment: Declaring copy constructors private is indeed totally common, many classes don't have well-defined copy semantics. Declaring otherwise meaningful copy constructors private, then wanting to grant arbitrary exceptions is not normal. :)

Comment: Do you allow move-construction? Then you could move your object into a tuple.

Comment: And since you are using c++11 anyway, it is better to `= delete` copy constructor instead of making it private.

Comment: @IlyaPopov I actually cannot `= delete` because the copy constructor is used by other hidden-from-the-user classes within the framework. And move-construction, if I understand correctly, would actually slide the problem over to the private default constructor. Maybe if I had to choose the lesser of 2 evils, an accidental default construction is more acceptable than an accidental copy construction.

Comment: Another example of dubious design practices ran amok. One should only prohibit copy construction (and usually assignment operator) when sematics of the class do not allow for copying. When the class has value semantics, it should be copyable. Performance associated with copying is not something class writer should worry. `std::vector<>` has copy constructor, despite this being potentially slow operation.

Comment: @dshin You not necessarily need default construction. All tuple member constructors accept rvalue-references: `tuple<Object, int> t(std::move(x), 35);` It represents a problem, however, if the framework is not ready for non-copyable types. In that case, ideally the framework shall be fixed.

Comment: @IlyaPopov Ah, I gotcha. I like this solution.

Comment: @dshin Be aware, that the `tuple` containing your object becomes non-copyable itself. Which the framework may not like.

Answer (score 1):

If the framework requires your class to be copyable, you really should provide a copyable class.

If your class really is only movable, or not even that, then maybe the framework should have a `std::unique_ptr` or similar to the object instead? Or you could create a movable adaptor class around that `std::unique_ptr` which forwards the interface...

Part of the forward-facing interface to users of the class is, whether it is moveable and/or copyable. If you are trying to make it non-copyable, unless you happen to be a component of the target application area... this limits code reuse, and it may confuse potential users of the class as to whether or not it is safe to copy / move it.

It may be that the framework doesn't really need to make a copy, and can be refactored to make moves instead?

It's very unclear from the question why you don't want it to be copyable. You seem to say that bad things will happen, but for some reason you aren't concerned if the framework makes a copy. Is it really okay to make copies or not?

It may be that you need to make a separate system for tracking / enforcing the invariant that you are concerned about, rather than just try to prohibit copying this class.